# Passing services to services as dependency

Tags: angularjs

Below I have a factory called Position that returns data that the whole app needs to use about the users current position and other models. Under that is a service called Romanize that contacts an external URL which provides a kind of translation, but Romanize needs to access to the app data provided by Position. I tried with the usual DI but it fails. How can I inject Position into Romanize as a dependency?

```
app.factory('Position', function(){
    return{
      questionNumber: 0,
      tutorialNumber: 0,
      sectionNumber: 0,
      sections: sections
    }
});

app.factory('Romanize', ['$http', 'Position', function($http){
    alert(Position);
    return{
      Position: Position,
      get: function(){
          $http.get(Position.sections[Position.sectionNumber].romanizeService).success(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to add `Position` as a parameter in the Romanize factory function.

```
app.factory('Romanize', ['$http', 'Position', function($http, Position){
```

The string `'Position'`, tells Angular to inject the position service as the second argument (the `$http` service being the first).

Comment: ah, so i did, thank you. Do the arguments passed to the function need to have the same name as the strings or do they know what they are just from the position they're in?

Comment: No, only the order matters. However, if you don't use the array syntax but only the anonymous function, then the names are important, but in your case they are not.